# Login problems because of firebase database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My firebase database has the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
         ".read": "auth == null",
         ".write": "auth != null"      
       }
}
```

Due to which I am not able to login into my app even though I am using the valid email id and password. When I change my rules to the one below, things work perfectly fine.

```
{
  "rules": {
         ".read": "auth != null",
         ".write": "auth != null"      
       }
}
```

My app has a requirement in which the users need to read certain value of a specific child stored inside the database even if they are not authenticated users. But changing rules to `".read": "auth == null"` is causing login problem. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"auth == null"` means the user is logged out and only logged out users can read that data. If you want to give access to anyone, simply set it to ".read": true.